# pull value from multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays

i have 2 arrays as below

```
data1[]=array ( 0 => 0, 1 => array ( 0 => 4, 1 => 8, ), 2 => 0, 3 => array ( 0 => 2, 1 => 6, 2 => 10, ), 4 => array ( 0 => 1, 1 => 5, ), 5 => array ( 0 => 3, 1 => 7, 2 => 11, ), )

data2[]=array ( 0 => 0, 1 => array ( 0 => 1, 1 => 5, ), 2 => array ( 0 => 4, 1 => 8, ), 3 => 0,  )
```

i am trying to compare each element of array one with each of array 2 and ahow it on screen

my code is

```
for($i=0;$i<9;$i++){

   if( is_array($data1[$i]) == "1")
   { $sourcecount=count($data1[$i],1); }

   else{$sourcecount=1; }

       //echo $sourcecount."<br>";
     for($j=0;$j < $sourcecount;$j++){

      if( is_array($data2[$j]) == "1")
       { $endcount=count($data2[$j],1); }

       else
       {$endcount=1; }
       //echo $endcount."<br>";

         for($k=0;$k<9;$k++){
             for($m=0;$m<$endcount;$m++){
                if( is_array($data1[$i]) == "1")
                { $source=$data1[$i][$j]; }

                else
                {$source=$data1[$j]; }


                if( is_array($data2[$k]) == "1")
                { $end=$data2[$k][$m]; }

                else
                {$end=$data2[$m]; }


                echo $i.$j." ".$k.$m." - ". $source." ".$end."<br>";

             }
         }
     }
 }
```

but i now getting the output as

```
00 00 - 0 0 
00 10 - 0 1 
00 20 - 0 4 
00 30 - 0 0
```

its missing the

> ```
> 00 11 - 0 5
> 00 21 - 0 8
> ```

and i get error

> Array to string conversion

on

> echo $i.$j." ".$k.$m." - ". $source." ".$end."
> ";

at times

i am unable to figure out y its coming so...as the values are not getting printed properly or i get the error

Comment: The arrays must not have the indexes you show. The error means there's no `0 =>` element in the array.

Comment: i have pasted the content of the array as u can see  0 => is present in it

Comment: can you paste the results of `var_export($data1)` and `var_export($data2)` so we can paste them into test programs?

Comment: `$k<=$endcount` should be `$k<$endcount`

Comment: Why don't you use `foreach` instead of `for`? then you don't have to worry about indexes.

Comment: @Barmar yes i ahve updated the code with the arrays..plz have  a look... thank u

Comment: `data1[] =` should be `$data1 =`

Comment: I can't reproduce the error: https://ideone.com/QJD5vT

Answer (score 0):

Here's what you could do. Use a **recursive function**. I created an alternative of your function where you can have infinite depth. Even if `$a[3]` is an array and `$b[3]` is an int, it will validate the int with each value of `$a[3]` array. If you wish to disable that, you could only change the OR to an AND where you check if `$a_data` and `$b_data` are array.

Here I created another function `array_depth` to check how deep is the array. I then pad, by adding 0, on the result at the end of `compare_rec`.

```
<?php

$a = array (
    0 => 0, 
    1 => array(
        0 => 4, 
        1 => 8,
    ), 
    2 => 0, 
    3 => array(
        0 => 2, 
        1 => 6, 
        2 => 10, 
    ), 
    4 => array(
        0 => 1, 
        1 => 5,
    ), 
    5 => array(
        0 => 3, 
        1 => 7, 
        2 => 11, 
    ), 
);

$b = array(
    0 => 0, 
    1 => array(
        0 => 1, 
        1 => 5,
    ), 
    2 => array(
        0 => 4, 
        1 => 8, 
    ), 
    3 => 0,
);

$max_depth = max(array_depth($a), array_depth($b));
echo compare_rec($a, $b, $max_depth);

function array_depth(array $array) 
{
    $max_depth = 1;

    foreach ($array as $value) 
    {
        if (is_array($value)) 
        {
            $depth = array_depth($value) + 1;

            if ($depth > $max_depth) 
            {
                $max_depth = $depth;
            }
        }
    }

    return $max_depth;
}

function compare_rec($a, $b, $max_depth, string $resp = "")
{
    $result = "";
    $longest_array = max(is_array($a) ? count($a) : 1, is_array($b) ? count($b) : 1);

    for($i = 0; $i < $longest_array; $i++)
    {
        $a_data = (is_array($a) ? (isset($a[$i]) ? $a[$i] : 0) : $a);
        $b_data = (is_array($b) ? (isset($b[$i]) ? $b[$i] : 0) : $b);

        // If either of $a_data or $b_data are array, rec the function
        if (is_array($a_data) || is_array($b_data))
        {
            $result .= compare_rec($a_data, $b_data, $max_depth, $resp . $i);
        }
        else if (is_numeric($a_data) && is_numeric($b_data))
        {
            $result .= "00 " . str_pad($resp . $i, $max_depth, "0") . " - " . $a_data . " " . $b_data . "\n";
        }
    }

    return $result;
}
```

If there's something else, just ask.

Comment: i m getting error Call to undefined function array_depth()